# Nested divs wrap in undesired priority

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with how my nested divs behaves with line breaks. I have tried searching for this, but to no avail, since the problem is hard to put in words.

I have four divs nested as indicated below, all with display inline-block:

```
-------- ---------------------------
| menu | | content holder div      |
| div  | | ----------- ----------- |
|      | | | content | | content | |
|      | | | div 1   | | div 2   | |
|      | | |         | |         | |
-------- | ----------- ----------- |
         ---------------------------
```

Now, the menu div and the content divs have flexible width that depens on the data loaded. When either content div gets too wide, I want the following to happen:

```
-------- ----------------------
| menu | | content holder div |
| div  | | -----------        |
|      | | | content |        |
|      | | | div 1   |        |
|      | | |         |        |
-------- | -----------        |
         | ------------------ |
         | | content div 2  | |
         | |                | |
         | |                | |
         | ------------------ |
         ----------------------
```

But instead I get the following:

```
--------
| menu |
| div  |
|      |
|      |
|      |
--------
---------------------------------
| content holder div            |
| ----------- ----------------- |
| | content | | content div 2 | |
| | div 1   | |               | |
| |         | |               | |
| ----------- ----------------- |
--------------------------------|
```

It is very confusing when the menu div is tall enough to hide that any content was loaded whatsoever. Also, keeping the menu div width fixed would only be considered as a definite last resort. The divs could however be made floats instead of inline-blocks, if that would help.

Does anyone know a simple way to keep the layout as in fig. 2? I have tested that this still happens when either content div would fit as in fig 2 if the other content div was invisible.

edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/pzHhL/1/

Comment: provide HTML/CSS part of the code that you have done in a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Easy and simple add `max-width` for you div "content holder div", i could give you the numbers but you didnt give a jsfiddle.

Comment: But the max width would depend on the width of the menu div, which is variable, so I cannot set that.

Comment: You beat me to the answer because I was creating a fiddle.  Rather than compete with you, I've upvoted your answer and will share my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wjW9s/1/.

Comment: @user2401411, I think you're confusing `width` and `max-width`.  The `width` depends on the menu div, but you'll need to set a `max-width` irrespective of the menu div.

Comment: I mean that I want the content holder to utilize remaining screen real estate, and not limit it to say 50%.

Comment: In that case it would be ok to wrap, but as long as either of the content divs would fit alone, they should be next to the menu.

Comment: So the best way to do that is using JavaScript, because you doesn't have one rule, you have many rules that you can't apply with CSS only

Comment: @user2401411, 50% is just an example for demonstration purposes.  You choose your own `max-width`.

Answer (score 1):

Switching them to floats would help to keep the layout you're looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/pXdDy/

giving the inner content divs

```
min-width:48%;
margin:1%;
float:left;
```

would sit them beside each other until the content gets wide enough to push them down

Comment: In the fiddle the widths are constant, I need them to be variable for all the divs.

Comment: the inner divs have a fixed `min-width` but will expand out to full width depending on content - http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/pXdDy/1/